# Meaning and difference of *is finished* and *have been finished*?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the difference between *is finished* and *has been finished*?

What is exact meaning of *have been finished*?

Example
a)  My Tablets are finished

And

b)  My Tablets have been finished

Correct me if I am wrong
Meaning of Sentence

Meaning of Sentence a)To Tell someone *Present status* of finished tablet to someone

Meanings of Sentence b)To tell someone *time frame* that my tablets are finished since some time back i.e. Since 3 days.

Or

To tell someone that somebody has finished my tablets i.e. another patient.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

*My work is finished* indicates the current status of the work.

*My work has been finished* indicates that the work has had that status for some length of time, e.g. for three days.

Normally, if we wanted to say that someone else has done the work, we would add a prepositional phrase:

**My work has been finished *for me*.**

And we might also add to the end "by my colleague" or something like that.